# How do we configure custom error page for 404, Outside the Application war

Tags: java

Suppose this is my application - (localhost:8080/myApp/servlet/HomeServlet)

If I pollute the servlet with junk say **localhost:8080/myApp/servlet/HomejunkServlet** I get 404 in response which I can redirect to generic custom-err-page by configuring web.xml.

But What if I request for an application that doesn't exist ex: localhost:8080/myApp-tht-doesn-exist/servlet/HomeServlet, it will still give me default 404, eventhough I configured my web.xml to handle 404 error. How do I redirect to a custom error page in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Server handles non-application-contexts as resource-requests.
So, place an Webapp as ROOT.war to the server that configures his own error.jsp for code 404.

It should be even better to use an Apache-HTTP-Server to dislplay error-pages if 
even your Application-Server is down.